# Izpack Console installation

Tags: linux, console-application, izpack

I'm trying to get a Headless Installer working (install from command line for remote Linux)

But everytime I run the command, I get this instantly

```
java -jar install.jar -console
[ Console Installation done ]
```

What do I have to do to get the installer to work with the -console command, I would rather get this to work than to resort to using an automatic installation XML file

Here is my Izpack XML using  izpack 5.0.0

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes" ?>

<!-- 
    A sample installation file.
    Use it as a base for your own installers :-)

    To compile it :
    - go in the bin directory where you installed IzPack
    - call "compile ../sample/install.xml -b ../sample"
-->

<installation version="1.0">

    <!-- 
        The info section.
        The meaning of the tags should be natural ...
    -->
    <info>
        <appname>EMEProvisioningSDK</appname>
        <appversion>${project.version}-Linux</appversion>
      <!--
        <authors>
            <author name="Anthony Lafleur-Tighe" email="anthony.lafleur-tighe@ericsson.com"/>
        </authors>
        <url>http://prodcat.ericsson.se/frontend/category.action?code=FGB%20101%20652&path=%5cNavigation%20Root%5cFGA%20101%2017%5cFGB%20101%20743%5cFGB%20101%20399</url>
Roll       -->
    </info>

    <!-- 
        The gui preferences indication.
        Sets the installer window to 640x480. It will not be able to change the size.
    -->
    <guiprefs width="640" height="480" resizable="yes"/>

    <!-- 
        The locale section.
        Asks here to include the English and French langpacks.
    -->
    <locale>
        <langpack iso3="eng"/>
    </locale>

    <!-- 
        The resources section.
        The ids must be these ones if you want to use the LicencePanel and/or the InfoPanel.
    -->
    <resources>
        <res id="LicencePanel.licence" src="Licence.txt"/>
        <res id="InfoPanel.info" src="Readme.txt"/>
        <res id="ProcessPanel.Spec.xml" src="installProvisioningPanelSpec_linux.xml" />
        <res id="shortcutSpec.xml" src="shortcutSpec_linux.xml" />
    </resources>

    <!-- 
        The panels section.
        We indicate here which panels we want to use. The order will be respected.
    -->
    <panels>
        <panel classname="HelloPanel"/>
        <panel classname="InfoPanel"/>
        <panel classname="LicencePanel"/>
        <panel classname="TargetPanel"/>
        <panel classname="PacksPanel"/>
        <panel classname="InstallPanel"/>
        <panel classname="ProcessPanel" />
        <panel classname="ShortcutPanel"/>
        <panel classname="FinishPanel"/>
    </panels>

    <!-- 
        The packs section.
        We specify here our packs.
    -->
    <packs>
        <pack name="Base" required="yes">
            <description>The base files</description>
            <file src="Readme.txt" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="Licence.txt" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="unzip.exe" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="changePermissions.sh" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
        </pack>
        <pack name="MCDProxy" required="yes">
            <description>The MCDProxy</description>
            <file src="install_mcd.sh" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="mcdproxy-component-eme-resource-assembly.zip" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="global-config.zip" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="MCDPROXY-CXC1736424-win32.zip" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="postgresql-jdbc-driver.jar" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
        </pack>
        <pack name="Tomcat" required="yes">
            <description>Tomcat 7, web container for Provisioning Agent</description>
            <file src="tomcat-7.0.20-noarch-full.zip" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="install_tomcat.sh" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="tomcat-users.xml" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="security-component.jar" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="libsysutils-component.jar" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="libsysutils.so" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="common-oam.jar" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="common-debug.jar" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="common-cache.jar" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="common-mcd.jar" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="common-crypto.jar" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="mcc_common.jar" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
        <file src="common-xml.jar" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
    <file src="mcc_mfs.jar" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
    <file src="mcc_sm.jar" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="security-component.jar" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="authentication-api.jar" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="mcc_identityformatter.jar" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="mail.jar" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="javax.mail-api.jar" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="mio-valve.jar" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="mio-filters.jar" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="mio_startup.sh" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
        </pack>
        <pack name="Provisioning Agent" required="yes">
            <description>The Provisioning Agent</description>
            <file src="install_pa.sh" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="provisioningagent-web.war" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="provisioningagent-eme-config-assembly.zip" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="samples.zip" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>

        </pack>
        <pack name="PostgreSQL" required="yes">
            <description>PostgreSQL Relational DB</description>
            <file src="postgresql-9.1.2-150.1.x86_64.rpm" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="postgresql-libs-9.1.2-66.1.x86_64.rpm" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="postgresql-server-9.1.2-150.1.x86_64.rpm" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="pg_hba.conf" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <file src="install_postgresql.sh" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            <executable targetfile="$INSTALL_PATH/changePermissions.sh" type="bin" stage="postinstall" keep="true" failure="warn" os="linux">
             <args>
               <arg value="$INSTALL_PATH"/> 
              </args>
            </executable>
        </pack>
    </packs>
</installation>
```

Comment: You really should state your izpack version and post your install.xml if you expect a useful answer here. Did you try adding -DTRACE=TRUE to the command line to get more information?

Comment: you're right, I added my XML file
also with Dtrace I get this Initializing builtin conditions for packs.
Pack.getCondition(): null for pack Base1
Pack.getCondition(): null for pack MCDProxy
Pack.getCondition(): null for pack Tomcat
Pack.getCondition(): null for pack Provisionin
Pack.getCondition(): null for pack PostgreSQL

Comment: There is no version 5.0.0 released yet (last one is 5.0.0-rc1 released yesterday), so you probably are using on of the beta releases, which simply may not work correctly. My guess would be to try this with 5.0.0-rc1. I built a working console installer with this version. You install.xml shows nothing suspicious on first glance.

Comment: I managed to make it work by doing <panel classname="com.izforge.izpack.panels.hello.HelloPanel"> for every panel, it's pretty weird. I did however just try with the5.0.0-rc1 release and it worked flawlessly with my old code. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Change line

```
<installation version="1.0">
```

to

```
<installation version="5.0">
```

IzPack 5.0.* will not work properly with version 1.0.